# Solution Verification for Problem Finding constant $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{a(2x-\pi)\cos x+b}{\sin x-1}=1.$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

> Find $a$ and $b$ such that
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{a(2x-\pi)\cos x+b}{\sin
>  x-1}=1.$$

I try answer as follows.

The denumerator is zero when $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Now I assumed numerator is equal to $0$ (because if the numerator not equal $0$, the RHS is infinity). Then $b=0$ must hold. Now I try to using L'Hospital rule as below.
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{2a\cos x-a(2x-\pi)\sin x}{\cos x}&=1\\
\iff \lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{-2a\sin x-2a\sin x-a(2x-\pi)\cos x}{-\sin x}&=1\\
\iff \lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(4a+a(2x-\pi)\cot x\right)&=1\\
\iff 4a&=1\\
\iff a&=\dfrac{1}{4}.
\end{align}
So, we have $a=\dfrac{1}{4}$ and $b=0$. Is it correct answer? I'm not sure with my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I think. For me it's better to use the following substitution: $x-\frac{\pi}{2}=y$ and we can get a solution without L'Hosptal.

Comment: Your method is absolutely correct and so is your answer. Just a suggestion , When you are in doubt of your answer you can always verify using graph in desmos. Or you can use something like wolframalpha.

Comment: Is it just me who think there are some serious problems with the language and so, the method to deduce $b=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without l'Hospital, to verify we can also proceed by standard limits,  by $y=\frac \pi 2-x \to 0$

$$\dfrac{a(2x-\pi)\cos x+b}{\sin x-1}=\dfrac{-2ay\sin y+b}{\cos y-1}=\frac{y^2}{1-\cos y}\dfrac{2ay\sin y-b}{y^2}$$

from which we obtain the same answer.